# Issues with installing python libraries on Windows : CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64

Tags: python, ssl, https, anaconda, conda

I'd like to install the pymongo library but I'm getting the following error:

```
    (C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3) C:\Users\xxxxxxx>
    conda install -c anaconda pymongo

    Fetching package metadata ...
    CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/a
    naconda/win-64/repodata.json>
    Elapsed: -
    
    An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
    HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
    
    ConnectTimeout(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', por
    t=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /anaconda/win-64/repodata.json (Caused by
     ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000
    00000054D6128>, 'Connection to conda.anaconda.org timed out. (connect timeout=9.
    15)'))",),)
```

Steps taken to resolve:

```
1. Update C:\Users\\xxxxxxx\.condarc file with the following:

channels:
  - defaults
ssl_verify: false
proxy_servers:
http: http://sproxy.fg.xxx.com:1000
https: https://sproxy.fg.xxx.com:1000

2. (C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3) C:\Users\xxxxxxx>
    conda config --set ssl_verify False
```

Additional Info:

```
(C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3) C:\Users\xxxxxxx>
conda info

Current conda install:

               platform : win-64
          conda version : 4.3.27
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.27
    conda-build version : 3.0.22
         python version : 3.6.2.final.0
       requests version : 2.18.4
            config file : C:\Users\xxxxxxx\.condarc
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
             user-agent : conda/4.3.27 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.2 Windows/7 W
indows/6.1.7601
          administrator : False
```

A number of posts online simply reinstalled Anaconda, any other options apart from a fresh install?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

**This works a charm:-**

Just copy these:-

1. `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll`
2. `libssl-1_1-x64.dll`

from `D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin` to `D:\Anaconda3\DLLs`.

Comment: Worked for me to, any explanation on what went wrong? Why are these not already present?

Comment: Amazing, it worked for me. I tried turning off ssl_verify, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Luk164 Idk maybe some error while installing or maybe it'd work fine if we install it on the C drive.

Comment: I also tried the set ssl_verify method above then tried this. This ultimately worked for me.

Comment: If you add the Library\bin to path variable, you wouldn't need to copy and paste the files

Comment: After doing this, removing the existing env and recreating that worked out for me

Comment: For Win 11 Pro Insider Preview using PyCharm with Conda, this worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much @Swapnil...it took a minute to install and I crossed my fingers but it works like a charm!!!  I'm going to set my environment per Imran as well.  Thanks so much guys!!!  I hope your numbers go up big time!

Comment: What about Python 2.7? The folder doesn't contain these files. However, It doesn't worked for me using Python 3.8.

Comment: Logged in to my account specially to upvote this answer!!

Comment: Close your anaconda prompt and open it again to check if the solution worked for you or not.

One more thing is, if you are behind proxy then please set your proxies in env variable.

Answer (score 98):

Execute the following command in the cmd prompt/terminal:

`conda config --set ssl_verify no`

Comment: Its not a good idea to unset ssl verification unless you know what you are doing. The other answer works for me for a brand new anaconda installation on windows.

Comment: that is exactly what anaconda tells you to do in the docs [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/?highlight=CondaHTTPError%3A%20HTTP%20000%20CONNECTION%20FAILED#id58).  they don't explain why.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. I tried re-installing Anaconda, upgrading anaconda, changing my path variable, and moving the DLL's around. This definitely makes me uncomfortable too

Comment: If you navigate to the repo from your browser `https://repo.anaconda.com` and you receive a warning like NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID then this is your best solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 35):

I try to create a virtual env with python 2.7 with anaconda, the base env is python 3.7. I encounter the exactly same problem. It turns out that there isn't such problem with other virtual envs with python 3.7 or 3.6.

[This post](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6007#issuecomment-467457872) works perfectly to solve my problem on win7 with anaconda prompt.
It basically says you need to add the following directories into your user environment path in windows (go to `Start` and type in: `View Advanced System Settings`, then select `Environmental Variables`: then select `Path` and click `Edit`: finally you can click `New` and add a path):

C:\your_directory_to_anaconda3\Anaconda3\Scripts

C:\your_directory_to_anaconda3\Anaconda3\

C:\your_directory_to_anaconda3\Anaconda3\Library\bin -- This is the directory for openssl

Comment: Oct, 2021. This is still working for me.

Comment: Great answer that doesn't involve tinkering with files or security It works as of Sep, 2022.

Comment: OP should accept this answer as this is the actual correct one. The others are unnecessary work arounds.

Answer (score 18):

If you added conda to your PATH variables, remove it and use the "Anaconda Prompt". This solved the problem for me.

See: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8046#issuecomment-450582208

Comment: thank you, this is the right fix. It it too tempting to add conda.exe location to path and then try but that causes a lot of trouble. Anaconda Prompt has all the right settings to get conda working.

Comment: I almost gave up. It was around 2 am when I saw this man. It solves everything

Answer (score 10):

I faced this issue when I tried to create environment. I solved it by first activating conda base environment by using:

```
conda activate base
```

then I created the environment

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.7
```

Comment: This was what I needed, none of the other fixes had an impact.

Answer (score 8):

1. Check the proxy URL
2. Verify `.condarc` file

For me, the problem was with the indentation in the `.condarc` file.

```
proxy_servers:
  http: http://testproxy:8080
  https: https://testproxy:8080
```

Comment: In my case, the mistake was the file named"condaarc" instead of ".condaarc" (leading "." missing)

Answer (score 4):

My authenticated proxy server is configured with a domain whitelist for massive and repeated downloads so root or local sudoer doesn't need to be authenticated.
Adding  conda.anaconda.org is not enough as this repo redirect its traffic to amazonaws.com.
In my case, adding ".amazonaws.com" to the whitelist solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was resolved by adding a username and password to file C:\Users\xxxxx.condarc

```
channels:
  - defaults
ssl_verify: false
proxy_servers:
  http: http://xxxxx:password@sproxy.fg.abc.com:yyyy
  https: https://xxxxx:password@sproxy.fg.abc.com:yyyy
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on Windows 10-64 bit and intuitively installed the 64-bit version of miniconda. However, it results in exactly the same error above. Installing 32 bit conda installer has resolved the issue

Answer (score 3):

My issue was simply not running the conda init command prior to attempting to create an environment.

Answer (score 2):

Before installing some package (`pydicom`) the installation run just fine. After 
 it I tried to install `matplotlib`, but I got the same error as yours.

I tried `conda config --set ssl_verify no` but it didn't solve the problem so I set it again to true.

Fortunately, I had a virtual environment where I installed my packages. I closed all Anaconda prompts and tried in a new `test` environment. Magically, the install worked. I came back to my original virtual env and run the install again, and it worked!.

It might be that I just had to wait for some time before I could use `conda install` again.

One other thing I could do is remove the package that caused the problem, but I didn't have the chance to try it. If it has anything to do with some virtual environments not being affected, then one possible way to guard against this is to clone the environment before installing any new package.

**Edit**: I tried the same solution but It did not work. But instead of showing the error immediately, it asks me whether I want to proceed.  I deactivated the env, and re-opened anaconda prompt, then did the same steps as above and worked again.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the Same Issue, I resolved by installing 32 bit Anaconda Installer.
Which resolved the CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION, on Windows 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issues after "conda clean -a" on win-64.
Activating and deactivating existing conda env resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to upgrade your openssl installation

You can download it here (Try the latest version):

https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Source:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6424#issuecomment-464660808

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda for all users (instead, of current user only, requires admin privileges) and activating the option to add Anaconda to PATH during the installation process, fixed the issues for me.

[image]

Comment: This is what fixed it for me, deleted the folder it installed to, re-ran the installer, checked this box (didnt have it checked prior), error went away.

Answer (score 1):

Came across the CondaHTTP Connection error after installing Anaconda environment on a new Windows 10 computer. I tried virtually all the recommendations above unsuccessfully! Looking up the Anaconda archives ( https://repo.continuum.io/archive/ ), I downloaded the immediate previous release .... and on installation and rebooting my PC, all is now well[screenshot of release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9p1P.png)

Answer (score 1):

In short - installing **Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio** solved my problem.

In more detail: upon trying a [suggested solution](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6007#issuecomment-478194302) of installing a new version of [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), the installation process told me I was missing a dependency - the Visual Studio Redistributable package. The installer led me to a direct download page of the 2017 version. I can't find that page now, but the official release of 2019 can be found [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), and should work as well (found under *Other Tools and Frameworks*).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your responses. In my case, I found out that my Kaspersky Internet Security was blocking it the whole time. The moment I quit the application all applications were downloaded. Please check your firewall settings before trying all the above options.

Answer (score 1):

This error can be resolved with the **change of python version** . For me it was giving error in python 3.9 but for 3.8,3.7 running completely fine.

Or you can just do complete uninstallation of anaconda and then reinstall it.

Note : Update the anaconda if there is any update

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of these solutions and none worked for me. After running the command

`conda config --remove-key channels`

in the Anaconda Prompt, everything started working for me on my next attempt.

Comment: this is probably only the reason when you have "channels" in your config file

Answer (score 0):

Adding that I had the same problem on ubuntu on WSL. None of the solutions worked for me, until I realized I was working on WSL version 1 (I thought I'd already upgraded). Upgrading from WSL 1 to WSL 2 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Running following these two commands worked for me.

```
conda config --remove-key proxy_servers
conda clean --source-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd tried all of the advice on this and many other webpages.
In the end I broadcast a "help me Obiwan Kenobi, you're my only hope message" to a large group of people at work and one of them who used python all the time was able to help me

The trick was to set several windows environmental variables

CURL_CA_BUNDLE

REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE

SSL_CERT_FILE

To my company's root certificate (a .cer or .crt) which I had downloaded to a spot on my disk

You may also need to add (in my case)

C:\Users\kdalbey\Anaconda3\Scripts

(or your particular \Anaconda3\Scripts) to your path.

And then I set proxies just for good measure
note I previously copied libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, libcrypto-1_1-x64.pdb, libssl-1_1-x64.dll, libssl-1_1-x64.pdb from anaconda3\Library\bin to anaconda3\DLLs so that could be part of the secret sauce

and it didn't work until I killed and restarted anaconda-navigator

Answer (score 0):

Two steps to deal with this error.

1. The Anaconda prompt configures the path, to include all the necessary executable files (for instance `Library\bin` - On Windows, launch it with admin permission). So that you need to use it to execute `conda` :

[image]

2. Update conda with `conda update conda`

Answer (score 0):

Exit my proxy software which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would like summarize some of the proposed answers in this post and propose my experience on that. As it can be understood from the error explanation, the error is related to the connection and I strongly believe that **no need to uninstall and reinstall anything** if the real cause of the problem be known. My problem gone away after the system powered off and powered on again one day later. So, some possible causes and their solutions (these solutions could be tested in order based on the written bulleted order) could be as follows:

- **Crash in anaconda prompt:**

  **Probable solutions:**

  1. Deactivating and activating the environment, without removing all packages or …, or
  2. Closing/reopening the prompt ([Michael Heidelberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54238978/13394817)) or
  3. Using `cmd.exe` instead, perhaps
- **Non-responsiveness of the anaconda site:**

  Massive site traffics related probable issues, that could be the reason of non-responsiveness or to temporary block some IPs
  **Probable solutions:**

  1. Retying as recommended in the error: *HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.* **It solves my problem sometimes.** or
  2. Activate or deactivate VPNs or Proxies (like use in `.condarc`; see: [Github sroder](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6007#issuecomment-372679096), [Nandhan Thiravia](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6007#issuecomment-490403995), [Vinod Sangale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62369135/13394817), [Peter Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50128847/13394817), [Sunding Wei](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73742702/13394817)).
  3. Try after a while if you have time
- **System firewall block the site:**

  That might be happened by activating and deactivating of VPNs, repeatedly or by some other works
  **Probable solutions:**

  1. Finding the issue in system firewall and allowing the connection in the firewall settings ([ScienceJedi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63087109/13394817), [Github](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6007))
  2. Reboot, perhaps

---

If the aforementioned ways didn't solve the problem, testing the related answers in the following order:

1. Add `...\Anaconda3\Scripts`, `...\Anaconda3\`, and `...\Anaconda3\Library\bin` to the path ([talentcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55943881/13394817), [skerjj](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6064#issuecomment-453147166), [Victor Ochieng](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8046#issuecomment-477676392), [jankap](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8046#issuecomment-456028676)), perhaps need a reboot after ([lightarrow](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8046#issuecomment-473915134))
2. Copying `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` from `D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin` into `D:\Anaconda3\DLLs` ([Swapnil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62483686/13394817))
   I think it could be used in the first step because It is unlikely to be cause of any other problem. The reason I didn't mention this at the beginning is that the developers could placed these files in that directory during installation, too, in default, but they didn't; perhaps it had some reasons ([Github](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8046)).
   Note: these files are for Python `>3`, and I didn't find them for Python 2. Perhaps they have another names.
   ***It must be said that my problem didn't solve by this solution.***
3. Keep your SSL stack up-to-date ([kamal dua](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51719759/13394817), [Anaconda troubleshooting](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/?highlight=CondaHTTPError%3A%20HTTP%20000%20CONNECTION%20FAILED#http-000-connection-failed), [update openssl](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6007#issuecomment-360493145), [Abdulrahman Bres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59985610/13394817), [Update to openssl 1.1.1](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8046#issuecomment-450227886))
   I didn't recommend it at first because *Its not a good idea to unset ssl verification unless you know what you are doing* ([Pratyush comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3773658/pratyush)) and somewhere I read that it couldn't return to `True` again.
   ***It must be said that my problem didn't solve by this solution, too.***

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
conda update openssl ca-certificates certifi
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue on Mac, my resolve method is:

add trace log config to conda config file, modify the `~/.condarc`

```
verbosity: 3
```

then conda will print all trace in terminal, my issue

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/jonathan/sslkeylogfile/keylogfile.log'
```

then create the `sslkeylogfile` directory solve my issue

```
mkdir ~/sslkeylogfile
```

It's ridiculous...