# CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.continuum.io/pk gs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I need to install Tensorflow and was trying to add up environment first. But I get HTTP Connection Failed error. I'm behind a corporate proxy and already defined them well in .condarc file. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\Rahul\Downloads>conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6 anaconda
Solving environment: failed
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url 
<https://repo.continuum.io/pk
gs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -
An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your 
way.
ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io, por
t=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused
by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0
000001A00393C88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinf
o failed',))",),)
```

I posted this issue in their issue tracker here in detail:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7283

As mentioned in issue tracker, I already tried resetting ssl, adding condarc file etc. But no luck so far. My proxy is working as expected and my entries in condarc file are correct. Also continuum repository is accessible via browser without issues.

None of the commands like `conda update` or `conda install` works and gives the same error stack while executing.

What might be going wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issues with installing python libraries on Windows : CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125472/issues-with-installing-python-libraries-on-windows-condahttperror-http-000-co)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Apparently, the condarc file was updated and rewritten as an empty
> file while I ran config command. I tried running proxy settings and
> trusted host through command line, but it doesn't work. But then found
> that invoking trusted host through command line is discontinued and so
> I added the same in pip.ini file. After that it worked!

Like I mentioned in the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7283), I added below in pip.ini and it worked

```
trusted-host = pypi.python.org pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org
```

Comment: i searched for pip.ini file.  It is not there.

Comment: @Nguaial 
**pip.ini** is the configuration file for Windows. It will be **pip.conf** for Linux/Mac.  
Refer to below documentation for finding respective path in your OS:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration

Comment: @Nguaial You then need to add it manually to a directory of choice in `pip config -v list`. Then open an empty txt file, save it as pip.ini. Put `[install]` in the first line if you start with an empty pip.ini to avoid: `Configuration file could not be loaded. File contains no section headers. file: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\pip\\pip.ini', line: 1 'trusted-host = pypi.python.org pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org'`

Answer (score 24):

I faced the same issue in Windows 10 machine and the below solution helps
Add the following paths to environment variables:

1. `Anaconda3\Library\bin`
2. `Anaconda3`
3. `Anaconda3\Scripts`

Answer (score 12):

On windows 10 machine:

1. Navigate to "Environment Variables" - How to navigate to `[environment_variables][1]`
2. Click on "Path"
3. Click "New" and copy and add the following path:
4. "C:\Users\yourusername\Anaconda3"
5. "C:\Users\yourusername\Anaconda3\Scripts"
6. "C:\Users\yourusername\Anaconda3\Library\bin"

Comment: This worked for me, but why is this the case? I already had `Scripts` in my path but had to add the other two to get it to work. Error message only talks about http error, so adding.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure why, but I was missing the `\Library\bin` line. After adding that third line to my variables it works.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Screenshot of error message]

I strongly recommend to copy libcrypto-1_1-x64.*
libssl-1_1-x64.* from .\Library in Anaconda folder to .\DLL in Anaconda folder. I'm 100% sure that your problem will be solved. Please don't crack your heads looking for solution on all the platforms.

Comment: No DLL\ directory, but other .dll in the 'root' of the conda dir and copying crypto & ssl .dll's to the conda root worked!

Answer (score 8):

****CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED****

This error comes many time for me too.
I tried others solution like

****`conda config --set ssl_verify no`****
but not fixed and finally I figured out!

Just open Anaconda prompt instead of CMD and type all the commands there, it will fix your problems!

**Anaconda Prompt(left)  ............................................              Windows CMD(right)**
[image]

Comment: conda config --set ssl_verify no worked for me! thanks for sharing -)

Comment: conda config --set ssl_verify no worked for me. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You managed to create a new environment from the conda prompt but not from `cmd` because your shell wasn't initialized yet.

1. Run `conda init cmd.exe` to initialize cmd.
2. Reopen your `cmd` shell (**must**).
3. Test `conda activate` and `conda create` commands which should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found that invoking trusted host through command line is discontinued and so I added the same in pip.ini file. After that it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Use Anaconda's own command prompt instead of windows one and type in the following command. No need to mess with `pip.ini` file

```
conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x
```

Answer (score 0):

I update the .condarc file

```
channels:
  - http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free
  - http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge
  - http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/bioconda
  - http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the mentioned conda paths to the windows path (they were missing) did not fix the problem for me, nor did using the conda prompt. In fact, in the conda prompt, I noticed another problem: "The system cannot find the path specified", right when starting the prompt. I then ran "conda init" in the conda prompt, and that apparently fixed the problem. (Possibly in combination with having added the paths earlier.)