# Anaconda Prompt error 'The system cannot find the file specified' and condaHTTPerror

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

[image: Snapshot of Anaconda prompt]

There are many error reports on 'The system cannot find the file specified', but almost all are very old threads with solutions not working now. And only a single query for similar problem for anaconda prompt without any solution.

When I open the anaconda prompt, the error message appears, but the commands work fine, except for the commands when i create new environment. I can not install or update any packages/libraries inside the created environment and prompt gives following error each time the error

```
conda install keras
Fetching package metadata ...
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda------/repodata.json
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
SSLError(SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",),)
```

## **Solutions I have tried**

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda3 - both 32 and 64 versions i have tried. I also tried restarting the laptop after uninstalling and befor installing fresh. I followed every step mentioned at https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/
2. Executing following command from command prompt -  [conda config --set ssl_verify no]
3. Creating the pip.ini file inside pip folder and updating with lines mentioned in this thread.
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/52764896/11107306
4. Browsing through all drivers including display and network drivers for updates and updating them if necessary.
5. Adding system path variable for anaconda
6. Downloading and installing Win64OpenSSL application.
7. Cleaning conda using conda clean --all inside environment and then trying to install again, with n o success.

## **My system details**

- OS - Windows 8.1
- Platform - win64
- Anaconda  - 2019.10
- Conda version - 4.7.12
- Python -3.7.4 (Its work laptop with python 2.7.13 default on command prompt- preinstalled, which I can not remove.)
- NVIDIA GTX 960M (updated driver) with Cuda version 9

---

Please kindly help me. I have wasted almost whole day in this. Or should I just go for other alternative? Kindly suggest good alternative for anaconda, I will be needing machine learning based libraries for my project. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The installer has multiple options during the GUI dialog - which are you selecting?

Comment: conda config --set ssl_verify false after installation set it back, if not try pip install pandas . You can also check firewall /vpn blocking

Comment: pip install also didn't work for me. There was no problem with firewall blocking or company proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me from github.

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8273 
I have copied the following files  
  
libcrypto-1_1-x64.*  
libssl-1_1-x64.*  
from D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin to D:\Anaconda3\DLLs.

And this worked very well for condaHTTPerror. Now I can install using conda even within created environment.

**However** I am still getting the message on prompt 'The system can not find the file specified' each time I open the prompt or carry out the command. How I can resolve this issue? kindly help.

Comment: I started using Anaconda Powershell Prompt instead of Anaconda Prompt. Powershell prompt doesn't raise any issue. It's working fine. Can someone explain me the reason?

Answer (score 1):

copying the following files

libcrypto-1_1-x64.*
libssl-1_1-x64.*

from bin library to DLLS library worked for me
from C:\users\Alex\Anaconda3\Library\bin to C:\users\Alex\Anaconda3\DLLs.