# How to create an environment in conda?

Tags: python, conda, environment

I'm having an error when I try run the command

```
conda create --name myenv
```

Below is the full error report

```
(base) C:\Users\damieng>conda create --name myenv
Solving environment: done

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

`$ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Scripts\conda create --name myenv`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
                          Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Scripts\conda.exe
             CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
                          Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\python.exe
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\damieng
                     PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
                          Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
                          Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Microsoft Visual
                          Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Library\usr\bin;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Microsoft Visual
                          Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Library\bin;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Scripts;C:\Program
                          Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\bin;C:\Program
                          Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOW
                          S\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Win
                          dowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
                          Files\Mellanox\MLNX_VPI\IB\Tools;C:\Program
                          Files\Mellanox\MLNX_CIMProvider\lib\mft;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;C:\Program
                          Files\Citrix\System32\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\;C:\Program
                          Files\Citrix\Virtual Desktop Agent\;C:\blp\DAPI;C:\blp\DAPI\DDE;C:\Ana
                          conda3;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program
                          Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Azure
                          Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\damieng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C
                          :\Users\damieng\.dotnet\tools;C:\blp\DAPI;C:\blp\DAPI\DDE;C:\Program
                          Files\Azure Data Studio\bin
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program
                          Files\Mellanox\MLNX_VPI\Tools\WMI\Modules;C:\Program
                          Files\Mellanox\MLNX_CIMProvider\WMI\Modules
         PYTHONIOENCODING=1252
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\damieng\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\damieng\.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.4
    conda-build version : 3.10.5
         python version : 3.6.5.final.0
       base environment : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\pkgs
                          C:\Users\damieng\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\damieng\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\envs
                          C:\Users\damieng\.conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.4 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/pro/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([(\'SSL routines\', \'ssl3_get_server_certificate\', \'certificate verify failed\')],)",),))',),)

A reportable application error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
```

After few hours looking up online I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: does this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305725/condahttperror-http-000-connection-failed-for-url-https-repo-continuum-io-pk?

Comment: try ``conda create --name myenv python=3.6``

Answer (score -1):

Your issue and your question can be very different.

Your issue has something to do with `SSL` connection: `SSLError(MaxRetryError(`. Try to check if your internet connection is working well, try to access https://repo.anaconda.com to see if it works.

Your question of "how to create an environment in conda" has been answered many times here, and it is documented on the official website. BUT make sure to pay attention to these confusing commands below, you can either run

- `conda create -n test`, OR
- `conda env create -f environment.yml` where `environment.yml` is a configuration file

Also note that `conda env create -n test` will not work any more.

See [this](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) for the latest docs.