# Installing fbprophet Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda, facebook-prophet

My build keeps failing on windows 10 for installing fbprophet in anaconda with the following message:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::automat-0.7.0-py_1'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\bharat.c.ruparel\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
```

the command that is given is:

conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet

Has anyone successfully installed fbprophet on Windows 10?  If yes, then please give the steps.

Thanks.
I tried pip install as well but no luck.  I have a Mac and managed to install fbprophet on it without any issues.

Comment: As of v1.0, the package name is `prophet`; prior to v1.0 it was `fbprophet`. Given that, already updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64878241/7109869).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated: 28 July 2022**

As of v1.0, the package name on PyPI is "prophet"; prior to v1.0 it was "fbprophet". `fbprophet` is now just `prophet`. A few additional considerations:

- From v0.6 onwards, Python 2 is no longer supported.
- As of v1.1, the minimum supported Python version is 3.7.

Below one will find how to

1. Install with PyPI
2. Install with Anaconda
3. Install the Development version

---

**1. Istallation in Python using PyPI**

Prophet is on PyPI, so one can use pip to install it.

```
python -m pip install prophet
```

---

**2. Installation in Python using Anaconda**

One might have to access `Anaconda Prompt` **for the environment that one is working with** as admin:

[image: Access Anaconda Prompt as admin]

And run

```
conda install -c conda-forge prophet
```

Or

```
conda install -c conda-forge prophet -y
```

---

**3. Development version**

To get the latest code changes as they are merged, one can clone [this repo](https://github.com/facebook/prophet) and build from source manually. This is not guaranteed to be stable.

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/prophet.git
cd prophet/python
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
python setup.py develop
```

By default, Prophet will use a fixed version of `cmdstan` (downloading and installing it if necessary) to compile the model executables. If this is undesired and one would like to use one's existing `cmdstan` installation, one can set the environment variable `PROPHET_REPACKAGE_CMDSTAN` to `False`:

```
export PROPHET_REPACKAGE_CMDSTAN=False;
```

---

**Sources**

1. https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html
2. https://github.com/facebook/prophet

Comment: I hardly make comments, but this has solved my problems. Thank you and +1.

Comment: Nice! but how does this work for an Atom environment?

Answer (score 26):

1. First install Anaconda or miniconda in your Windows machine and add conda python path to env variable as default python.
2. Open your command prompt and run following commands.
3. Create a conda virtual environment (optional)

   ```
   conda create -n v-env python=3.7

   activate v-env
   ```
4. Install c++ complier

   ```
   conda install libpython m2w64-toolchain -c msys2
   ```

   libpython will automatically create and setup `distutils.cfg` file for you in `PYTHONPATH\Lib\distutils`, but if that is failed use the following instructions to setup it manually

   ***[OPTIONAL]***

   create `distutils.cfg` with text editor (e.g. notepad, notepad++) and add the following lines to that file.

   ```
   [build]
   compiler=mingw32
   ```
5. Install dependencies

   ```
   conda install numpy cython -c conda-forge

   conda install matplotlib scipy pandas -c conda-forge
   ```
6. Install PyStan

   ```
   pip install pystan

   or 

   conda install pystan -c conda-forge
   ```
7. Install Ephem

   ```
   conda install -c anaconda ephem
   ```
8. Install fbprophet

   ```
   pip install fbprophet

   or 

   conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
   ```

Comment: I was getting "CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for u". I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125472/issues-with-installing-python-libraries-on-windows-condahttperror-http-000-co

Comment: N.B., The package was renamed from "fbprophet" to "prophet" for version >= v1.0.0.   As of 7/22/2022, Python 3.7 or higher is now required.  For details see: https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html

Comment: @Akash Ukarande ... After the step "create distutils.cfg with text editor" where should the [OPTIONAL] file "distutils.cfg" be located?

Answer (score 12):

I also faced installing facebook prophet issue in windows 10 without conda.
But,we can solve it.
First, uninstall any pystan, fbprophet.
Then follow the steps below,

```
python.exe -m pip install pystan==2.17.1.0
python.exe -m pip install fbprophet==0.6   
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade fbprophet
```

Thanks,
tsj

Comment: Does not work for me on Python 3.8; fails at step "Building wheel for pystan". [IgorJerosimić](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111433/igor-jerosimi%c4%87) : Which C++ compiler do you have? (Tried with rtools 4.0 which includes mingw32)

Comment: Worked for me too, and I just did a pip install fbprophet, instead of install and upgrade, after the pystan install, so probably something to do with the pystan version. In this link https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html#installation-in-python, they mention pystan version 2.19.1.1

Comment: N.B., The package was renamed from "fbprophet" to "prophet" for version >= v1.0.0.   As of 7/22/2022, Python 3.7 or higher is now required.  For details see: https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html

Answer (score 8):

I've had the same problem. But it works after I follow this steps:

On Prompt install Ephem:

`conda install -c anaconda ephem`

Install Pystan:

`conda install -c conda-forge pystan`

Finally install Fbprophet

`conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet`

Comment: N.B., The package was renamed from "fbprophet" to "prophet" for version >= v1.0.0.   As of 7/22/2022, Python 3.7 or higher is now required.  For details see: https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html

Answer (score 3):

Latest installation code for 2021:

`pip install pystan==2.19.1.1`, then `pip install prophet`

Also, reboot your jupyter notebook after installation

Comment: N.B., The "fbprophet" package was renamed from "fbprophet" to "prophet" for version >= v1.0.0.  Also, as of 7/22/2022, Python 3.7 or higher is now required. For details see: facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html

Answer (score 2):

Install without `Conda, Win 10, Python 3.8.8 64 bit`.

```
pip3 install Cython
```

Then [install](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/visual-cpp-build-tools/):

Reboot your maching

Install

```
pip3 install pystan==2.17.1.0

pip3 install fbprophet
```

Comment: Do you mean "for Macintosh or Linux, NOT Windows"?  Your answer title is confusing, but the use of "pip3" indicates that you are on a Mac or Linux platform.  Please clarify.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. I have not use conda-forge before, so reading up on this [article](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html) helps.

1. Making sure that conda is ≥4.9

```
conda --version
```

2. add conda forge channel

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda --set channel_priority strict
```

3. install gcc

```
conda install gcc
```

4. install prophet

```
conda install -c conda-forge prophet
```

I used the [prophet documentation](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html) here

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and my solution was to:-

Create a new environment with Python3.5

```
conda create -n pht python=3.5 anaconda
```

Install Prophet using the command.

```
conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
```

I didn't install 'gcc' although this was advised before installing Prophet.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Python 3.8.5` and `conda 4.10.1` on a Windows 10 machine.
I was able to install prophet in `Anaconda 2.0.1` using command prompt (**not** as admin), using: `conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet`
It took some time for it to figure out the details, as you can see from the prompts below, but finally it was able to install the package.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
```