# Numpy error when installing fbprophet Python on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, numpy, anaconda, facebook-prophet

I'm trying to install [fbprophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/) on my win10 64 bit machine (anaconda). I've followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178281/installing-fbprophet-python-on-windows-10) [here](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178281/installing-fbprophet-python-on-windows-10), but I keep getting the same error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

~\Anaconda3\envs\fbprophet\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     15 if missing_dependencies:
     16     raise ImportError(
---> 17         "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
     18     )
     19 del hard_dependencies, dependency, missing_dependencies

ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "C:\Users\Ran\Anaconda3\envs\fbprophet\python.exe",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.0" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I assume it has something regarding the numpy version, but the version in the virtual environment I've created for fbprophet is as required (1.17). It seems that this evnironment tries to use different version of numpy.
I have numpy installed in my anaconda base and in other virtual environments and there is nothing wrong with it. It happens only when I try to install fbprophet.

UPDATE:
I was able to solve the problem by uninstall numpy (v 1.17) and install instead numpy v1.16

Comment: Once you've followed the Windows instruction for pystan, did you pip install pystan ?

Comment: yes, I did installed pystan

Comment: I understand, but did you install it with `pip` or with `conda` ?

Comment: I tried both as suggested in the links I posted