# Not able to install fbprophet within pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, dllimport

Hi I am a python newbie and am trying to install fbprophet within pycharm but am getting the following error. I have successfully installed pystan though.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: fbprophet
  Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for fbprophet
Failed to build fbprophet
Installing collected packages: fbprophet
  Running setup.py install for fbprophet: started
    Running setup.py install for fbprophet: finished with status 'error'

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ankita.gupta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\fbprophet\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ankita.gupta\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\fbprophet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\ANKITA~1.GUP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-9u7mn7vi' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\ankita.gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\fbprophet\
  Complete output (40 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib
  creating build\lib\fbprophet
  creating build\lib\fbprophet\stan_model
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\ankita.gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\fbprophet\setup.py", line 120, in <module>
      """
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\ankita.gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\fbprophet\setup.py", line 44, in run
      build_stan_model(target_dir)
    File "C:\Users\ankita.gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\fbprophet\setup.py", line 27, in build_stan_model
      from pystan import StanModel
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pystan\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
      from pystan.api import stanc, stan
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pystan\api.py", line 13, in <module>
      import pystan._api  # stanc wrapper
  ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Any ideas on how to resolve it, anyone?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Comment: Have you already tried it with pip directly?

Comment: `Tim Woocker` Yes ...giving same error

Comment: `NotSoShabby`  This solution did not work for me. I had already gone through the link before I posted the question

Answer (score 3):

First you have to Install c++ compiler, you can install c++ compiler

```
pip install libpython m2w64-toolchain -c msys2
```

Once c++ compiler installed you have to install pystan, to install pystan you can use below command

```
pip install pystan
```

Finally, now we are ready to install facebook prophet

```
pip install fbprophet
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, while installing fbprophet on Windows10 Pycharm virtual environment...

Solved this by first uninstalling any pystan, fbprophet I had already installed:

```
pip uninstall pystan

pip uninstall fbprophet
```

Then re-install those libraries using python.exe:

```
#PyStan:

python.exe -m pip install pystan==2.17.1.0

#fbProphet0.6:

python.exe -m pip install fbprophet==0.6 

#Upgrade fbProphet:

python.exe -m pip install --upgrade fbprophet
```

If you follow this steps, prophet should be successfully installed!

Test the installation by importing the library from python terminal:

```
Python 3.7.3 

>>> import fbprophet
>>>
```

Source:[Installing fbprophet Python on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178281/installing-fbprophet-python-on-windows-10)

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!