# pip install fbprophet on Windows without conda

Tags: python, windows, pip, facebook-prophet

I would like to install fbprophet on windows 10 without having to install Anaconda. I have python 3.7. I have tried all suggestions from [Installing fbprophet Python on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178281/installing-fbprophet-python-on-windows-10) without success.

So far I have installed pystan, as it is required before installing fbprophet, but when I run `pip install fbprophet`, I am getting a lot of red output, with the following errors:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: fbprophet
Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py) ... error
...
...
...
ImportError: DLL load failed: Specified module not found.
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

fbprophet backned is pystan. it seems pystan is not installed in your environment.you can verify it using: import pystan in your python environment