# Why I am getting this error after creating 10 Anaconda environments?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have created Conda environments with many names like `naive-bayes`, `flask_demo`, `project`, `mlops_main`, and so on, without any error and used them in many projects, but this time I tried to create environment using the following commands

1. `conda create -n rainfall_prediction python=3.6` or
2. `conda create --name rainfall_prediction`

but got some HTTP errors. Here is the error I am seeing:

[image: show the exact error after running command]

Note:- *I am getting same error for both command*

Comment: Pleas post your error message as text

Comment: You can refer to these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125472/issues-with-installing-python-libraries-on-windows-condahttperror-http-000-co

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issues with installing python libraries on Windows : CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125472/issues-with-installing-python-libraries-on-windows-condahttperror-http-000-co) That is, it's the internet connection (which has nothing to do with your choice of environment name); possibly sitting behind a firewall (need to add proxy) or Anaconda is not responsive (it happens), among other things.