# CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url on CentOS 6

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am getting the following error when I try to install anything on my conda. I tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125472/issues-with-installing-python-libraries-on-windows-condahttperror-http-000-co), but nothing is working on `CentOS 6`.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/linux-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/linux-64'
```

UPDATE: Here are the solutions that worked:

1. I downloaded [ca-certificate](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ca-certificates/2021.10.8/download/linux-64/ca-certificates-2021.10.8-ha878542_0.tar.bz2)  and [openssl](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/openssl/1.1.1k/download/linux-64/openssl-1.1.1k-h7f98852_0.tar.bz2)  and saved it to a directory
2. `conda install /PATH_to_directory/openssl-1.1.1k-h7f98852_0.tar.bz2`
3. `conda install /PATH_to_directory/ca-certificates-2021.10.8-ha878542_0.tar.bz2`

Comment: Allegedly just [installing an earlier version](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10146#issuecomment-1008866500) should fix the problem

Comment: I tried to avoid that as I have many packages installed and few envs created. I did not want to re-install all those packages again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your `conda-meta/history` file, it shows the last one that worked for you
2. downloaded ca-certificate and openssl and saved it to a directory
3. `conda install /PATH_to_directory/openssl-1.1.1k-h7f98852_0.tar.bz2`
4. `conda install /PATH_to_directory/ca-certificates-2021.10.8-ha878542_0.tar.bz2`