# How do I fix the CondaHTTPError

Tags: r, anaconda, conda

I am on a corporate laptop with RStudio. The spacyr package is downloaded and attached, and when I run the following:

```
install_spacy()
```

I get the following message:

```
c" "conda-forge"
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64'


Error: Error creating conda environment 'spacy_condaenv' [exit code 1]
```

I've tried the tip I've been seeing in response to similar questions where you copy paste the libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
libssl-1_1-x64.dll
files into Anaconda3/Library/DLLs and that hasn't changed anything either.
I've also executed `conda update --all`, and tried `conda config --set ssl_verify no` but again, nothing.

Is it a problem that I'm trying to execute this through R Studio rather than Anaconda?

Comment: The function name is `spacy_install`, not `install_spacy`.

Comment: Voting to close. Even if the error is not due to misspelling the function name, there still insufficient information about OS, versions and setup details to offer any suggestion other than the one possibly not done -- to try again as recommended. When I ran `R> spacy_install()` ( after `$ conda update -n base -c defaults conda` )  through Rstudio on my Linux 18.04 box I got reports of success (after waiting a long time.)

Comment: No, RStudio should not be the issue. There are still many other possibilities in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125472/issues-with-installing-python-libraries-on-windows-condahttperror-http-000-co), e.g., proxy settings. While I don't believe this is a typo and don't find an Ubuntu replication compelling (Windows + Conda is a special problem), the answer should be found in the duplicate. But please ping me if more info is added that shows this is unique - I'd be happy to consider reopening.