# Can't Create an Environment with Conda

Tags: anaconda, conda

Have tries many of the suggestions on the web (such as setting SSL to false in conda config, etc) to no avail hoping someone can help. I am trying to create a new conda environment and am getting the following error (I also can not update my existing environments). This is running on an AWS box if relevant. Greatly appreciate any guidance. The link that is being tried seems fishy, atoti is the name of one of my other environments (but I am trying to create the new environment from base).

```
(base) PS C:\Users\ncosgrov> conda create --name HREnv
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
```

> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.atoti/win-64/current_repodata.json
> Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
> HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
> 'https://conda.atoti/win-64'

Have tried conda config --set ssl_verify false as recommended in one article. Have also opened hole in firewall for conda.exe

The one thing I note is that the URL it is trying to hit ***https://conda.atoti/win-64/current_repodata.json*** seems off.  What should it be and where can I override/fix it?

Comment: Are you using windows? Have you checked the Anaconda environment variables? Have you tried adding the 3 of them? `C:\Users\mk\Anaconda3`, 
`C:\Users\mk\Anaconda3\Scripts`,
`C:\Users\mk\Anaconda3\Library\bin`

Comment: Yes.  I had already added them; no joy.

Comment: sad to hear that... Have you tried copying `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll `from `D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin` to `D:\Anaconda3\DLLs` ? [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125472/issues-with-installing-python-libraries-on-windows-condahttperror-http-000-co)

Comment: I had done that, however I found the issue, it is a bad channel.  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.  It was a bad channel that had been added a while back, it was that URL that was failing not the URL to the update, but it was blocking anything else.

Many thanks to the community, the exercise of having to describe the issue to someone else actually caused me to realize what was goin on.

Comment: Great! If you did anything specific, post it as well in the answer so future users with this problem can have another possible solution!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).