# Conda error http 000 when trying to install libraries on Windows

Tags: python, ssl, anaconda, conda

Since yesterday I have been having problems with `conda`. To preface, I've tried everything in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125472/issues-with-installing-python-libraries-on-windows-condahttperror-http-000-co/62483686#62483686). The only thing I'm not sure I've done right is the proxy servers because I've never done something like that.

Now, the background. I work at an organization that has many network blocks, but `conda` worked without problem. I was able to create environments and install libraries. But, yesterday I needed to create an environment with `tensorflow` and Windows told me the path was too long. Wasn't able to extend path length because of the blocks, so I tried to uninstall miniconda and reinstall it in C:/ . Since then, problems emerged. Libraries installed from `conda-forge` were returning a Timeout with the dreaded

```
 CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64
```

But, packages from other channels did work, I could do something like this: `conda create -n myenv tensorflow gensim`. I googled and tried everything, uninstalled, reinstalled in the original path, but the problem just kept growing. Now I'm getting that error every time, I can't install anything using `conda install`.

After running the debugger I noticed the problem is I can't make a request to a page like `https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json`. Even if I try on Python using requests, on R, using `curl` or Postman, I'll get a  Timeout. BUT, that same request works on the browser without problem.

That's all the background I've got. Does anyone have any idea? Any way to further understand why I'm getting a TimeoutError ?

Thanks a lot